# Passenger Apache 'undefined symbol: unixd_config'

Tags: apache, passenger

I'm trying to get apache running with passenger. I did:

```
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

After installing the other things it told me to install (e.g. apache2-prefork-dev) I added the lines it said to add to the http.conf file, and it tells me there's a syntax error on the LoadModule line.

```
user@machine:~$ sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart
httpd: Syntax error on line 174 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

That is referring to the following code which it told me to add:

```
174 LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
175 PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.13
176 PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Do you know why it can't find the unixd_config?

Thanks in advance!

Some info:
Rails v3.2.6, Ruby 1.9.2p320, gem v1.8.24, apache2 (I don't know how to find the version, but I know it's 2.x)

If it matters:

```
178 <VirtualHost *:80>
179     ServerName www.example.com
180     DocumentRoot /home/dylan/private/project/public
181 
182     <Directory /home/dylan/private/project/public>
183         Order allow,deny
184         Allow from all
185     </Directory>
186 </VirtualHost>
```

(also I have no idea what to put for ServerName if you want to help me with that too...)

Answer (score 3):

If you installed other apache before, you may have to need specify apache.

I tried the following command.

```
env APXS2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a case of having compiled the Phusion Passenger module against the wrong Apache version. As banrui says, you need to run the installer with the AXPS2 environment variable pointing to the right apxs2 command, namely that of the Apache installation you're intending to run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Hongli is correct.
To get your apache version:
 apachectl -V (I had to be root)

From
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/new_api_2_4.html
unixd_config
This has been renamed to ap_unixd_config.

You will have to rebuild passenger:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Comment: Thats it, rebuild passenger?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include /usr/include`

This helped me on Yosemite. Apparently, the symlink is not automatically created with the installation of Xcode 6.1. The symlink pointed to a previous SDKs include directory. The only thing that worked was changing the symlink.